# Better way to say x == Foo::A || x == Foo::B || x == Foo::C || ...?

Tags: c++, c++03

Let's say I have a bunch of well-known values, like this (but `const char *` is just an example, it could be more complicated):

```
const char *A = "A", *B = "B", *C = "C", *D = "D", *E = "E", *F = "F", *G = "G";
```

Now let's say I want to behave in a particular way if the result of some expression is in a subset of those:

```
if (some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type == A ||
    some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type == C ||
    some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type == E ||
    some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type == G)
{
    ...
}
```

I find myself typing this sort of thing often enough that I would like a shorthand for it.

If the language was Python, I could easily say:

```
if some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type in [A, C, E, G]:
    ...
```

Is there a well-known, portable way for me to express this similarly in C++03?

Note that the return type is itself ugly (almost as ugly as the return type of [lambda expressions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/typeof.html#typeof.moti)), so I certainly don't want to store it in a local variable.

But the return type does **not** have to match that of the constants -- for example, if the return type was `std::string`, it would *not* be implicitly convertible to `const char *`, but `operator ==` would be perfectly fine for the comparison.

So far, the best solution I have is to say something like:

```
const char *items[] = { A, C, E, G };
if (std::find(items, items + sizeof(items) / sizeof(*items),
              some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type)
    != items + sizeof(items) / sizeof(*items))
{
    ...
}
```

but it's pretty darn ugly. Is there a better way, which also works for non-PODs?

Comment: Isn't switch (some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type) {
case A:
case B:
case E:
do something;break;
} enough?

Comment: Only for integral types, which aren't ugly, so probably aren't present here.

Comment: @Benjamin: That's only for integral types, like Pete said.

Comment: In your "best solution", you include the return type. If it's acceptable there, why is it not acceptable for a variable?

Comment: @hvd: If it was acceptable then I wouldn't have asked this question! It's the best solution *I have*, but it's not a good solution.

Comment: What is this `==` in your example? Is it an `operator==` or a conversion followed by a comparison? In the latter case, you could perhaps simply store the converted result in a simple-to-name type like this `enum X`.

Comment: @MvG: No, like I already mentioned a bunch of times, I need something that works for non-PODs, like `std::string` and such.

Comment: It's confusing, if you are comparing something to POD (like enum X), that means, the first argument must be implicitly(or explicitly) cast to int(or enum), so I think the example is a little bit misleading in that case.

Comment: Even for non-PODs, if your current best solution is acceptable, that means that you can name the type `X` rather easily. If the comparison is for values of that type, you could cast to that first and compare there.

Comment: @Benjamin: Okay I'll fix the example, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @MvG: See my example -- you can't always cast. And like I said, it's the best solution I had so far, but I was looking for a more concise solution (like yours). I would *still* prefer a solution that didn't require me to name `X` at all, but so far the best I've seen is your answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could factor your current best solution into a template:

```
template<class A, class B, size_t n>
inline bool is_in(const A &a, B (&bs)[n]) {
  return std::find(bs, bs + n, a) != bs + n;
}
```

which you can use like

```
X items[] = { A, C, E, G };
if (is_in(some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type, items))
  …
```

Comment: Ahh, I like this... but it's still ugly with the return types.

Comment: @Mehrdad, Which return types? The one from your expression I'm treating as a black box here, so there is little I can do about it here. The only type you explicitely have to name is `X`, the type of the values you compare against. As you already refer to those values using names, I assumed that these at least have some reasonably short type name.

Comment: Oh my bad, you're right -- I confused `X` with the return type of the function. This looks pretty nice actually, I like this one the best so far! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 27):

If you have C++11:

```
auto res = some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type;
if (res == A
    || res == C
    || res == E
    || res == G) {
}
```

if not, you can still eliminate the type declaration by using a template function:

```
template <class T>
bool matches(T t) {
    return t == A || t == C || t == E || t == G;
}

if (matches(some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type)) {
}
```

Comment: I specifically mentioned I wanted to stay compatible with C++03... +1 though, since it might help others who have C++11.

Comment: Aren't you initialising `res` to `expression == A || res == C || ...`?

Comment: @hvd - yup. Bummer. I'll fix it.

Comment: Okay, then this answer isn't helpful at all, especially since the C++11 version doesn't even apply to C++03. I don't want to create a friend template function for every single `if (x == A || x == B)` that I have in my code!! That's *way* too unreadable and way too annoying to type. If you edit this again I'm probably gonna downvote it, sorry... :\ this definitely doesn't solve any problem.

Comment: It solves the problem in your original sample code (although not the sample as it was edited after I posted my answer). And remember, these posts are for the benefit of other readers as well. If the answer isn't helpful to you, that doesn't mean it won't be helpful to others.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Interesting, because my edit should not have affected your answer at all. I never said the return type was necessarily convertible to `X` in the first place (in fact, I quite obviously implied the opposite), so people who had that assumption were already mistaken in the original version. And I had *specifically* said I was looking for a solution that works for nontrivial cases ("non-POD"), so using `string` shouldn't have been surprising. Your answer just concentrated on the *example* while ignoring the real problem -- and it blatantly ignored the word "C++03". :\

Comment: @Mehrdad So your function's return type cannot be converted to `X`, but can be compared to `X`? I assumed it could be converted to `X` as well in my comment on your question, it would have been helpful if you had clarified then. That said, the second part of this answer is *still* correct for your question, even for C++03. The fact that you think it's ugly doesn't change that.

Comment: The original answer might have been helpful to others, but it was completely ignoring the whole reason I posted the question in the first place (nontrivial types in C++03). That said, thinking twice about it maybe I won't downvote your (current) *edited* answer since your C++03 solution is at least, well, a solution... even if it's really ugly. But I'll definitely remove the upvote I put earlier if it gets edited again. ;)

Comment: @hvd: Yes; I thought `string` would've been an obvious non-trivial example but evidently it wasn't, so that's why I edited it in response to Benjamin's reply. See the comment I just posted to Pete here.^

Comment: @Mehrdad I just want to have it mentioned somewhere here, but the only way to avoid typing the expression multiple times (other than macros) is to store the result in a variable, and the only way in C++03 to get type deduction for that variable is to have that variable be a template function parameter. So you'll either get a function like the `matches` function in this answer, or one of the things you specifically wanted to avoid. You liked MvG's answer, but that's actually the same principle as in this answer.

Comment: @hvd: Technically, yes. But MvG's answer is a heck of a lot more readable (and easier to type/maintain), because it leaves the meat inside the code, where it belongs -- not inside some random function living alone outside the namespace.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, MvG's answer is a significantly more generic and reusable version of this one :)

Comment: @hvd: Er, what I've been telling you is that it's a *bigger* issue than just genericity/reusability. It's **readability**. *MvG's answer leaves the logic coherent* -- you don't have to suddenly go hunting for a random function every time you come across an `if` statement like this. This one does the opposite -- it creates spaghetti logic, branching your code into all sorts of functions scattered around the file (and good luck finding them). One of them is readable, the other isn't. If you don't understand what I mean then never mind; I don't know how else to explain it, sorry.

Comment: @Mehrdad That's mainly a naming issue. If there's a simple logical name that matches the function's return value (say `X` is named `enum FoodType`, and `matches` is named `isFruit` which checks `Food::Apple`, `Food::Banana`, ... -- not a good example, but hopefully sufficient to show the point I'm making) there's nothing unreadable about creating specifically a `isFruit` function rather than a more generic one. It's not clear from your question that that's possible, nor that that's impossible.

Comment: @hvd: Uh, no, it's a *readability* issue; specifically, more of a scrolling issue than a naming issue. If you're inside a template class, for instance, you don't put the code right beside you if it doesn't depend on the template parameters -- so you have to find somewhere to put it *outside* of the class. Now just imagine scrolling and looking for it (with a text editor, for people who love text editors) every single time you're reading/debugging that code. It's sounds like a nightmare to me, but if this is normal practice for you then more power to you... *I* can't handle it, though.

Comment: @Mehrdad I suppose it depends on the situation, but I generally don't need to see the definition of my hypothetical `isFruit` when I see a function that calls it. I trust that it returns `true` when the passed argument is a fruit, and `false` when it isn't. If it doesn't, that doesn't affect the correctness of the calling function, that affects the correctness of the `isFruit` function.

Comment: @Mehrdad When debugging, the definition can be more useful (if just to make sure the function does what it claims to do), but my debugger jumping to the function I'm stepping through, to `isFruit` when it's called, means I don't have to look for it myself. (Actually, I can jump to `isFruit`'s definition when not debugging, but I don't need to all that often.)

Answer (score 12):

You could use a `switch`:

```
switch (some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type) {
  case A: case C: case E: case G:
    // do something
  default:
    // no-op
}
```

This only works with integer and enum types, note.

For more complex types, you can use C++11's `auto`, or for C++03, [boost's `BOOST_AUTO`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.auto):

```
auto tmp = some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type;
// or
BOOST_AUTO(tmp, some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type);

if (tmp == A || tmp == C || tmp == E || tmp == G) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The [`BOOST_AUTO`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.auto) in particular sounds like a very good match to what the OP asks.

Answer (score 9):

(Edit: Turns out my original trick with a dummy type didn't work, I was misled by a lucky accident in my tests. Let's try that again...)

With a couple of helper templates you can write a general solution for this kind of situation:

```
template <typename T1> class Matcher {
public:
    explicit Matcher(T1 t1): val(t1), flag(false) {}
    template <typename T2> Matcher& operator()(T2 t2)
        { flag |= val == t2; return *this; }
    operator bool() const { return flag; }
private:
    T1 val;
    bool flag;
};
template <typename T1> Matcher<T1> match(T1 t1) { return Matcher<T1>(t1); }

// example...
string s = whatever;
if (match(s)("foo")("bar")("zap")) { do_something(); }
```

You can match against as many arguments as you want.

Comment: Oooh I like this, can't wait to try it! Thanks! +1

Comment: The original OR expression will finish once any condition meets, but Matcher will try all conditions which is vital difference.

Comment: You can easily fix that by changing flag|=val==t2 to flag=flag||val==t2.

Answer (score 4):

Expressions of the type

```
if (some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type == A ||
    some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type == C ||
    some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type == E ||
    some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type == G)
{
    ...
}
```

are quite common in code (well, a pre-computed expression is anyway). I think the best you can do for readability is pre-compute the expression and **keep it as is**.

```
ugly_return_type x = some_complicated_expression_with_ugly_return_type;
if (x == A ||
    x == C ||
    x == E ||
    x == G)
{
    ...
}
```

Developers are used to this type of syntax. This makes it a whole lot easier to understand when someone else is reading your code

It also expresses what you want **perfectly**. There's a reason this type of syntax is so widely used in existing code - because other alternatives are worse for readability.

Of course, you could wrap the condition in a function, but only if it's reusable and it logically makes sense (besides the point IMO).

Comment: It's not always easy to get the return type, esp if you're using bind/lambda and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using variadic functions in c++03 as follows:

```
template <typename T>
bool MatchesOne( T _lhs, int _count, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,_count);
    for (int i=0;i<_count;i++)
    {
        int rhs=va_arg(vl,int);
        cout << "rhs = " << rhs << endl;
        if (_lhs == rhs) return true;
    }
    va_end(vl);
    return false;
}

int main(){
    float ff = 3.0;
    if (MatchesOne(ff, 5, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3))
    {
        cout << "Matches" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you know the types of all the expressions will have the same type as _lhs, you can change `int rhs=va_arg(vl,int);` to `T rhs=va_arg(vl,T);`

You can also do this elegantly using variadic templates in c++11:

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
bool one_equal(const T & _v1, const T2 & _v2)
{
    return _v1 == _v2;
}

template<typename T, typename T2, typename... Args>
bool one_equal(const T & _v1, const T2 & _v2, Args... args)
{
    return _v1 == _v2 || one_equal(_v1, args...);
}

...

if (one_equal(some_complicated_expression, v1, v2, v3, v4))
{

}
```

Okay one final hack-ish solution. It works, but makes the implementer of this function do a lot of repetitive work.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool match_one(T1 _v1, T2 _v2)
{
    return _v1 == _v2;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
bool match_one(T1 _v1, T2 _v2, T3 _v3)
{
    return _v1 == _v3 || match_one(_v1, _v2);
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
bool match_one(T1 _v1, T2 _v2, T3 _v3, T4 _v4)
{
    return _v1 == _v4 || match_one(_v1, _v2, _v3);
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4, typename T5>
bool match_one(T1 _v1, T2 _v2, T3 _v3, T4 _v4, T5 _v5)
{
    return _v1 == _v5 || match_one(_v1, _v2, _v3, _v4);
}
```

Comment: I wonder, too. Probably he has never seen variadic templates.

Comment: C couple notes... regarding the C++11 version: it's completely ignoring the fact that I said C++03 in the question. Regarding the C++03 version: varargs are very dangerous with non-PODs, and the code is error-prone, because it's quite easy for the `count` parameter to get out of sync with the rest of the args.

Comment: One more try added - c++03, no va_args. Requires a bit of busy work on your part, but if you are using it frequently throughout your program with a reasonably low number of comparisons, it won't take more than a few minutes to implement. Advantage over other solutions is that it allows comparisons of *any* type, so all the variables on the right hand side need not be of the same type (original question didn't stipulate one way or another).

Answer (score 0):

If not switch, maybe something like this, I didn't use it, but may be a draft to something working?

```
template <class ReturnType>
bool average(ReturnType expression, int count, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, count); //Requires the last fixed parameter (to get the address)
  for(int j=0; j<count; j++)
    if(expression==va_arg(ap, ReturnType))
      return true;
    return false
  va_end(ap);
}
```

Comment: Varargs are very dangerous with non-PODs.

Answer (score -1):

C++11:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
bool equalsOneOf (T1&& value, T2&& candidate) {
   return std::forward<T1>(value) == std::forward<T2>(candidate);
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename ...T>
bool equalsOneOf (T1&& value, T2&& firstCandidate, T&&...otherCandidates) {
   return (std::forward<T1>(value) == std::forward<T2>(firstCandidate))
     || equalsOneOf (std::forward<T1> (value), std::forward<T>(otherCandidates)...);
}

if (equalsOneOf (complexExpression, A, D, E)) { ... }
```

C++03:

```
template<typename T, typename C>
bool equalsOneOf (const T& value, const C& c) { return value == c; }

template<typename T, typename C1, typename C2>
bool equalsOneOf (const T& value, const C1& c1, const C2& c2) {
    return (value == c2) || equalsOneOf (value, c1);
}

template<typename T, typename C1, typename C2, typename C3>
bool equalsOneOf (const T& value, const C1& c1, const C2& c2, const C3& c3) {
    return (value == c3) || equalsOneOf (value, c1, c2);
}

template<typename T, typename C1, typename C2, typename C3, typename C4>
bool equalsOneOf (const T& value, const C1& c1, const C2& c2, const C3& c3, const C4& c4) {
    return (value == c4) || equalsOneOf (value, c1, c2, c3);
}

template<typename T, typename C1, typename C2, typename C3, typename C4, typename C5>
bool equalsOneOf (const T& value, const C1& c1, const C2& c2, const C3& c3, const C4& c4, const C5& c5) {
    return (value == c5) || equalsOneOf (value, c1, c2, c3, c4);
}

// and so on, as many as you need
```